# Run a script post login linux

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, login

I would like to run a script after a linux user logs in to do some additional security checks. The user should first login normally using their password, but then be checked with my script, and then get full access to the system. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure you really want to have it happen post-login?  With PAM you can do a lot of checking.

Comment: No I'd rather add an extra step to the authentification. Is that possible with PAM?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming all your users are using bash, then the file `/etc/profile` is executed on login.  On some distros there is an `/etc/profile.d`.  You could drop your login script into this directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this for EVERY user on the system that may log into a bash shell (basically root, and any other "normal" user), then you'll want to add the command into `/etc/profile` or add the script into `/etc/profile.d/` depending on your system.

If, however, you're trying to do this for a specific user, the place to add it would be into that user's `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`.

See [this page](http://bencane.com/2013/09/16/understanding-a-little-more-about-etcprofile-and-etcbashrc/) for more information on the files, as well as `/etc/bashrc`/`~/.bashrc`